# NuGet Get Latest Package From Feed

Tags: tfs, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

I have an environment where I'm building several library solutions in TFS.  At the end of the build process the script packages them into a NuGet package and pushes them to our local feed.

Now we can include these libraries, which change little day-to-day, in our upstream projects.

These libraries as well as our upstream projects generally are branched at the same version.  Basically the trunk is our evolving latest version. Say before branching the trunk is 3.0.0.123, 123 being a running build number.  At some point we mark the current trunk as what we're going to release and branch it.  The version number of the trunk at the time of the branch becomes the version of that branch and we would increment the version in whatever appropriate manner for the trunk to what we would feel is likely going to be the next release (say 3.1.0.456).

This presents a slight oddity to how we'd like to use NuGet.  We would want that the branch, 3.0.0.456, use the lateset library from the branch (perhaps 3.0.0.457) and the trunk to use the latest from the trunk (3.1.0.789)

So what this basically boils down to is can we setup the versions for a solution using NuGet to be similar to the manner NuGet uses when defining dependencies within a package?

Ideally, I'd like to tell the branched upstream application to use [3.0.0.456, 3.1) and the  trunk to use latest (no version). In this scenario it would pick up the branch would pick up the next branch build (3.0.0.457) and the trunk would pick up whatever the last NuGet package that was published to the feed.

The only idea that I've come up with as a possible solution is using parameters for the build template and using that to update the package.config file before the NuGet targets are run.

*I appologize if this should go on SuperUser or elsewhere...*

Answer (score 1):

After doing some digging to have my build do some auto creation of packages for our library projects I came to the (wrong) conclusion that this was a limitation of NuGet.  I parsed their source for any XSD documents to describe their XML so that I could see how their nuspec worked.

While I had their source I started looking into how I could modify the package.config file to accept their schema for limiting versions.  After some digging I found an attribute that can be added to the package node in package.config: allowedVersions.  This is exactly what I was looking to add!

Once I had this piece of information I was able to dig a little deeper into how it was implemented.  Turns out that this functionality has been around for a while and is even documented on their docs site: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning

It is in the dependency versioning guide located at the bottom.  I must have completely glossed over it or never read that far!

Turns out that this was a non-issue and the only problem was my ignorance.  Just a reference for any Googler's out there that land on this page!

SOURCE (LOCATED AT BOTTOM OF PAGE): [NuGet Versioning](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning)